# Ionic 2 - FCM custom sound notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have implemented FCM notification using PHP to send notification on mobile.
Notification working properly but I want to add sound to the notification.
I followed Ionic documentation for FCM.

```
this.fcm.getToken().then(token =>{
    alert("token : "+token);
});

this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
    alert("data :"+ JSON.stringify(data));

    if(data.wasTapped){
        alert("Received in background : "+ JSON.stringify(data.msg));
    } else {
        alert("Received in foreground : "+ JSON.stringify(data.msg));
    }
}, err =>{
    alert("Received err : "+ err);
})
```

My php payload:

```
$message['msg'] = 'notification text';
$message['sound'] = 1;
$message['vibrate'] = 1;

$fields = array(
 'registration_ids' => $tokenIds,
 'data' => array('message' => $message)
);
```

i'm sending `$fields` to notification plugin

Did anyone implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: show us, what you have done so far

Comment: please check question i have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your push notification payload set following properties.
You need to set `sound` property to `default`

```
    "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
```

Comment: I'm sending the notification from php server. I set property true but not works.

Comment: set `sound` property to 'default', refer updated answer

Comment: it's not working, notification is not coming in background

Answer (score 1):

At php server side i have set $fields array like this

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokenIds,
        'data' => array('message' => $message,
                        'click_action' => "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
                        'sound'=>'default'),
        'notification'=>array('message' => $message,
                            'click_action' => "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
                            'sound'=>'default'),
        'priority'=> "high"
    );
```

this can work for fcm notification at background and for sound in ionic